# Why is my python extension not loading in VScode? (Microsoft)

Tags: python, vscode-extensions

I'm new to Python and programming in general, i'm learning my first steps in VScode. I was trying to create a virtual environment which I couldn't activate for some reason. I tried to solve this with a few tricks I found on stackoverflow, like disabling python.experiments.

It still didn't work so I thought I would just start without a venv, but then the python extension was not working anymore. VScode told me: "Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information'"

The errors I found where: "Activation extension 'ms-python.python' failed: e.endswith is not a function"

I uninstalled the Python and Pylance extension, accordinly I deleted all the related files before installing it again.

I was expecting VScode to be loading the Python extension succesfully again, but I still encountered the same error for which I don't know how to solve it.

Then I deleted VScode entirely before installing it again, unfortunately still the same issue..

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_where-are-extensions-installed Delete the per user extensions folder, and then reinstall VS Code. The Python virtual environments are not easy to set up (too many tools and too little documentation), but you might get some ideas from https://docs.restructuredtext.net/articles/prerequisites#virtual-environments

Comment: Hi @LexLi thank you for your suggestion, I tried this procedure but I still get the same error message...

Comment: You will have to use Procmon on Windows or Linux to identify the actual files triggering the error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon That might guide you to the actual folder you have to delete.